# multiple forms in one page - reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building page where user can switch between login and signup mode by clicking the switch button.
Login form has 2 input fields and signup form has 3 input fields. My thinking was to build 2 separate forms independent from each other and use 2 separate custom hook instances.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { useForm } from "../../shared/hooks/form-hook";
import Card from "../../shared/components/UIElements/Card";
import Input from "../../shared/components/FormElements/Input";
import Button from "../../shared/components/FormElements/Button";
import {
  VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH,
  VALIDATOR_EMAIL
} from "../../shared/util/validators";
import "./Auth.css";

const Auth = props => {
  const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(true);

  const [formStateLogin, inputHandlerLogin] = useForm(
    {
      email: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false
      },
      password: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false
      }
    },
    false
  );
  const [formStateSignup, inputHandlerSignup] = useForm(
    {
      name: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false
      },
      email: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false
      },
      password: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false
      }
    },
    false
  );

  const loginSubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("login handler");
  };

  const signupSubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(formStateSignup.inputs);
  };

  const switchButtonHandler = () => {
    setShowLogin(!showLogin);
  };

  return (
    <Card className="authentication">
      {showLogin ? (
        <form onSubmit={loginSubmitHandler} className="place-form">
          <h2>Enter your login details</h2>
          <Input
            id="email"
            element="input"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            label="Email"
            validators={[VALIDATOR_EMAIL(), VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
            onInput={inputHandlerLogin}
            errorText="Please enter valid email address"
          />
          <Input
            id="password"
            element="input"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            label="Password"
            validators={[VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
            onInput={inputHandlerLogin}
            errorText="Please enter valid password (at least 5 chars)"
          />
          <Button type="submit" disabled={!formStateLogin.isValid}>
            LOGIN
          </Button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={signupSubmitHandler} className="place-form">
          <h2>Enter your signup details</h2>
          <Input
            id="name_s"
            element="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            label="Name"
            validators={[VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(2)]}
            onInput={inputHandlerSignup}
            errorText="Please enter valid name at least 2 chars"
          />
          <Input
            id="email_s"
            element="input"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            label="Email"
            validators={[VALIDATOR_EMAIL(), VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
            onInput={inputHandlerSignup}
            errorText="Please enter valid email address"
          />
          <Input
            id="password_s"
            element="input"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            label="Password"
            validators={[VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
            onInput={inputHandlerSignup}
            errorText="Please enter valid password (at least 5 chars)"
          />
          <Button type="submit" disabled={!formStateSignup.isValid}>
            LOGIN
          </Button>
        </form>
      )}
      <Button inverse onClick={switchButtonHandler}>
        {showLogin ? "SWITCH TO SIGNUP" : "SWITCH TO LOGIN"}
      </Button>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

Both forms seem to render fine but the trouble is when I enter text in one form and decide to switch to other form, values from departed form are not lost but rather translated to new form:

[image: login form]

[image: signup form]

Is this limitation of ReactJS, is it HTML? :) Or is it just my buggy code?

Comment: use different names of `state` for forms it will work

Comment: Didn't I already by using separate useForm hook instance???

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good convention to have two forms in one component, it makes a mess...I would make rather two separated components of LoginForm and SignUpForm and switch between them through ternary operator based on the `state` whatever way you like. Your forms and their state will be separated and code is more readable

Comment: Two forms on one page are super common. Take this page right here. There's a form for every thread. There's a search form up top. There's an answer form below. Components are just nested state machines and get bundled into larger components anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It happens same for checkbox and radio buttons if you select radio button on first page then renders second page with radio button it will be automatically selected as dom operations are costly,

In your case react is just adding new third field and removing it you need to set the value attribute of fields to respective state.

Comment: I've tried in my example but it's not picking it up correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

you can actually. use the nested route to switch between components

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<Switch>
   <Route path='/register' >
      // component 1
      <Register />
   </Route>
   <Route path='/login' >
      // component 2
      <Login />
   </Route>
</Switch>
```